# Django assignment_tag conditional

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show partials based on a simple condition. My condition is whether an `assignment_tag` is `True` or `False`.

Templatetag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.assignment_tag
def partner():
    return False
```

Template:

```
{% load partner_check %}

{% if partner %}
  {% block header %}
    {% include 'includes/partner_header.djhtml' %}
  {% endblock header %}

  {% block footer %}
    {% include 'includes/partner_footer.djhtml' %}
  {% endblock footer %}
{% endif %}
```

No matter what I set `partner` to, the blocks still appear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that's not how assignment tags work. You have never actually called the tag; `if partner` refers to a (non-existent) template variable named "partner". You call an assignment tag by using it on its own along with a variable to assign it to:

```
{% partner as partner_value %}
{% if partner_value %}...{% endif %}
```

Secondly, that's not how blocks work either. You can't dynamically define blocks; they are part of the basic structure of a template, not something that is assigned during evaluation.

Comment: Right, in this case my template is extending another template which has those blocks. I want to override those blocks - but only if a condition is met. This seems like a pretty common pattern in other frameworks, but I don't see much info on how to do this in django.

Comment: Probably with something like `{% block header %}{% if partner_value %}{% include .. %}{% else %}{{ block.super }}{% endif %}{% endblock %}`.

Comment: Yes, so two things to this. First, the arrangement of the conditional is important. You must do the conditional inside of the block.

Secondly, the variable. It is very hard to define a variable to check against in django, so I instead set it as a context_processor which makes the variable global to the app.

Comment: It's not hard to define a variable - as you found, context processors are a fine way to do it site-wide. For less global values, you generally set things in the view. Or, sometimes, define a method on a model instance that you expect to be available in your context - eg if you're writing a detail view.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this by using a `context_processor` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS)

Context Processor:

```
def partners(context):
    return {
        'partner': False
    }
```

Template:

```
{% block header %}
 {% if partner %}
  {% include 'includes/partner_header.djhtml' %}
 {% else %}
  {{ block.super }}
 {% endif %}
{% endblock header %}

{% block footer %}
  {% if partner %}
    {% include 'includes/partner_footer.djhtml' %}
  {% else %}
    {{ block.super }}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock footer %}
```